# Can a baby have a combination of traits transferred by the parents?

Tags: genetics, evolution

like: B=black color.
b=white color.
e.g.: one parent has genotype for skin color as (BB) and the other parent has genotype for the same trait as (bb).
can the child have the skin color which not too dark and not too white like brown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (I'm tempted to say "of course", as I would be surprised if you had not personally met families where the children had phenotypes intermediate between their parents' phenotypes ...)

This phenomenon is called **incomplete dominance**.  Now that you know the correct terminology you can easily do a [web search and get lots more information](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=incomplete+dominance) ...

Comment: thank you, i have been stuck on this question for a while and your answer really helped

Comment: any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: i didn't down vote you...

Comment: I know, I was addressing that to whoever downvoted ...

Comment: Can't speak for the down voter, but this does seem to the sort of question that we shouldn't be encouraging with answers — specifically from [How do I write a good answer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* This is ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) since it *`addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals`*. I personally prefer to direct users who appear to have little or no background knowledge to Khan Academy.